# How to match any text except one word

Tags: regex

Is there a way with a regular expression to match all characters and symbols except a particular word or particular combination of alphabetical chars?

Example:

```
Hello world!
```

`Hello` is literal and `world` may be different like `Hello Tom!`, `Hello Claudio!` etc.

But if in the word `world` or `Tom` or other the Regex engine encounters for example `or` or another combination of symbols then the word world will not match.

With this:

```
Hello (.*?)!
```

the engine will match all chars...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with [lookahead expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
Hello ((?:(?!or).)*?)!
```

will match any string after `Hello` that ends in a `!` and doesn't contain `or`.

```
Hello Tom!          // Match
Hello =)(/§  )$(/!  // Match
Hello Sailor!       // No match
```

If you only want to exclude entire (alphanumeric) words, you can use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
Hello ((?:(?!\bor\b).)*?)!
```

Results:

```
Hello Sailor!       // Match
Hello Tom or Jerry! // No match
```

Comment: I wanna to exclude both cases. a word or only a combination

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. Please edit your question and show some clear examples that define your problem.

Comment: @simpatico: [What](http://regexr.com?31bbv) do you [mean](http://regexr.com?31bc2)?